# Why it gets HTTP 404 error with @GET retrofit?

Tags: android, http, retrofit, response

Api

```
interface Api {
    @GET("device/{id}")
    suspend fun getDetails(@Path("id") id: String): DetailsResponse
}
```

IMO it's good that's my documentation.

```
curl -X GET https://myApiDocumentation/device -d "id=[MY_ID]" -H "Authentication: [API_KEY]" --cookie "auth_key=[AUTH_KEY]" -G
```

Error http 404

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project, PID: 21694
    retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 404 
        at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse(KotlinExtensions.kt:53)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:161)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

UseCase

```
class GetDetailsUseCase @Inject constructor(private val api: Api) : BaseApiRequestUseCase<GetDetailsUseCase.Params, DetailsResponse>() {
    override fun create(params: GetDetailsUseCase.Params) = flowSingle {
        api.getDetails(params.id)
    }

    data class Params(val id: String)

}
```

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class DetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(

    private val getDetailsUseCase: GetDetailsUseCase
) : BaseViewModel() {
    var details: Flow<DetailsResponse> =
        getDetailsUseCase.build(GetDetailsUseCase.Params(""))


    fun getDetails(id: String) {
        val params = GetDetailsUseCase.Params(id)
        details = getDetailsUseCase.build(params)
        details.onEach {
            val id = it.id
            val model = it.model
            Log.d("details", "WHAT IS IN THE PACKAGE +  $id $model")
        }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

DetailsResponse

```
data class DetailsResponse(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String,

   @SerializedName("model")
   val model: String,

)
```

fragment

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

// cameraId is value from previous fragment and it gives correct value
        getDetails(cameraId)
    }


    fun getDetails(id: String) {
        vm.getDetails(id)
        Log.d("details", "Fragment Det ${vm.getDetails(id)}")
    }
```

It crashes directly on it

```
details.onEach {
            val id = it.id
            val model = it.model
            Log.d("details", "WHAT IS IN THE PACKAGE +  $id $model")
        }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

What is your proposition to change the code, why it could go with error?
It is almost code above, but I hope I give you full information about my situation.

I tried to make it with `MutableShareFlow`, but I am not sure about how to make it.

EDIT:

```
2022-02-20 11:53:56.890 30031-30120/com.google.android.calendar I/SyncerLog: [1] Response: {applied_change_ids=[], done_change_ids=[], server_change_count=9, change_set_details={mark_to_be_deleted=[2(none), 1(none), 3(<some_calendar>), 3(<some_calendar>), 3(<some_calendar>), 3(<some_calendar>)], delete_all_marked=[2(none), 1(none), 3(<some_calendar>), 3(<some_calendar>), 3(<some_calendar>), 3(<some_calendar>)], run_cleanup=[4(<some_calendar>), 4(<some_calendar>), 4(<some_calendar>)], acl=3, calendarListEntry=4, calendarSyncInfo=0, event=0, habit=0, setting=28, other=[]}, updated_sync_state={synced_user_settings=true, synced_habits=true, synced_calendar_list=true}, bad_sync_state=false, debug_info=Ch41RDg3MEVFQ0ZCQjkxLkFDMjUzOTUuNzUwRkZCODg=, call_sync=false,
```

```
2022-02-20 12:50:23.651 31428-31428/com.example.api W/System.err:     at com.example.api.domain.CameraDetailsUseCase$create$1.invokeSuspend(GetDetailsUseCase.kt:12)
```

EDIT: FIXED
I should use Query instead of Path

```
interface Api {
    @GET("device")
    suspend fun getDetails(@Query("id") id: String): DetailsResponse
}
```

Comment: What does 404 mean?

Comment: I know what it means, I communicate with server but there is no such id in that case, but for sure there is. So what could be a problem maybe I wrote it wrong, my API ie

Comment: Maybe I should write in other way this line     @GET("device/{id}"), what do you think ?

Comment: What does 404 mean?

Comment: Did you set the base url when you init Retrofit ?

Comment: Yes, before I make auth and autorization and it works, base url is set correctly, blackapps I do not understand you. Please desribe me what it means, cuz if my answer is wrong i do not know. Thanks

Comment: Maybe I should ignore other variables if they are not necessary, thats way it ges error? Because in that API I've got many, many variables where I need to choose only 5

Comment: edit I put my response from stacktrace

Comment: It is fixed I should use QUERY... but another problem occurs if you guys want to help enjoy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71194354/why-it-gets-http-401-error-with-get-retrofit