# Why it gets HTTP 401 error with @GET retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, get, retrofit2, okhttp

When I would like to use `@Get` I get 401 HTTP error which means I am not authorized.
Before that I make `POST` on `/authentication` and `POST` on `/authorization` and it works I am successfully logged in.
The weird thing for me is I get two tokens, can someone explain why?

```
class AuthInterceptor(context: Context) : Interceptor {
    private val sessionManager = SessionManager(context)

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder()

        // If token has been saved, add it to the request
        sessionManager.fetchAuthToken()?.let {
            requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $it")
            Log.d("authorization", "$it")
// on authorization I get two tokens, after click Login first appears, 2 seconds later next one
        }

        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

Api

```
// I think I do not need add here @Headers if I use method in previous class requestBuilder.addHeader~

interface Api {
    @GET("device")
    suspend fun getDetails(@Query("id") id: String): CameraResponse
}
```

authApi

```
interface AuthApi {
    @POST("authenticate")
    fun login(@Body request: User): Call<AuthResponse>

    @POST("authorize")
    fun authorize(@Body request: AuthResponse): Call<AuthorizeResponse>
}
```

error from stacktrace

```
W/System.err: retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 401 
        at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse(KotlinExtensions.kt:53)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:161)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

My documentation

```
curl -X GET https://myApiDocumentation/device -d "id=[MY_ID]" -H "Authentication: [API_KEY]" --cookie "auth_key=[AUTH_KEY]" -G
```

If you need more code from program, here is my post which is fixed and another problem occurs...
[Why it gets HTTP 404 error with @GET retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71189706/why-it-gets-http-404-error-with-get-retrofit)

Comment: `I get 401 HTTP error which means I am not authorized. ` Ok. And what does HTTP error 404 mean? ;-)

Comment: blackapps plzz :D I do not have 404 anymore I put it in wrong link IMO, but if you have more suggesstions please tell, cuz I do not know for now.. ;(

Comment: 404 means my ID was not found in that case, but it doesn't give me any good information. I authorize, I get data from an user, and I use exact data from user and it still goes with 401, 404 before.

Comment: I'm not talking about your case. I'm talking in general. And the question is just what 404 means in general. If you know it for 401 then i think you would know it for 404 too.

Comment: I wrote my answer and you don't response for it so IDK how you would like to help in that case. I know what 401 and 404 means but it doesn't help me at all, null ;C :(

Comment: I will just try headers in other way, thank for interest anyway.

Comment: I just add header to interface API but still doesnt work. If someone could help me with this or just give some steps it would be nice. 
    suspend fun getDetails(@Query("id") id: String, @Header("authorization") token: String): DetailsResponse